# ActiveMQ server stops in JBoss EAP 7.2.8 after running for 1-3 days

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, activemq-artemis

**Setup:**
We have two JBoss EAP 7.2.8 instances in a cluster. JBoss also have Embedded AciveMQ broker with Colocated HA Topology and Oracle12c as persistence store.

ActiveMQ broker stops after running continuously anywhere between 1-3 days .

We get the following warning

```
2020-07-17 15:31:21,269 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.jdbc.ActiveMQScheduledLeaseLock] (Thread-10088 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@6e19beae)) - 117 : live lock renew period lasted 19998 ms instead of 10000 ms
2020-07-17 15:35:31,272 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.jdbc.ActiveMQScheduledLeaseLock] (Thread-10089 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@6e19beae)) - 117 : live lock renew period lasted 19971 ms instead of 10000 ms
2020-07-17 15:36:01,418 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-10106 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@6e19beae)) - 3618 : AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=NULL, message=Critical error while on live renew: java.lang.IllegalStateException: live lock can't be renewed
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.jdbc.ActiveMQScheduledLeaseLock.run(ActiveMQScheduledLeaseLock.java:92)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent$2.run(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:284)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)

2020-07-17 15:36:01,420 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.jdbc.ActiveMQScheduledLeaseLock] (Thread-10106 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@6e19beae)) - 117 : live lock renew period lasted 20082 ms instead of 10000 ms
2020-07-17 15:36:01,479 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-81 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) - 210 : AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
2020-07-17 15:36:01,493 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-81 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) - 210 : AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
2020-07-17 15:36:01,514 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-81 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) - 1869 : AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 8017bc3c-c77d-11ea-9fa8-005056a101d0
2020-07-17 15:36:01,515 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-83 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) - 210 : AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
2020-07-17 15:36:01,516 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-82 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) - 210 : AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
2020-07-17 15:36:01,517 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-81 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) - 1873 : AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 8017bc3c-c77d-11ea-9fa8-005056a101d0
```

All MDB's deployed in the same JBoss starts disconnecting and give below warning

```
2020-07-17 15:36:01,668 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-84 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) - 210 : AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
```

The ActiveMQ broker stops after sometime giving below info

```
2020-07-17 15:36:07,768 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-261) - 1285 : AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.9.0.redhat-00010 [7e4da338-c254-11ea-a652-005056a101d0] stopped, uptime 22 hours 36 minutes
```

Would really appreciate any clue/help on the above issue ?

Comment: Justin, do you have any suggestions on the above problem ?

Comment: Maybe you should try to find what caused the EAP shutting down. Perhaps IO problem with journal files? Try to turn on the EAP TRACE log to see more details.